# C++: "... is not a polymorphic type" while using boost::dynamic_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, shared-ptr, dynamic-cast

Why do I receive the following error for the following code?

```
1>C:\Libs\boost_1_44\boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp(259): error C2683: 'dynamic_cast' : 'my_namespace::A' is not a polymorphic type
1>          D:\[location]\[header_filename].h(35) : see declaration of 'my_namespace::A'
1>          C:\Libs\boost_1_44\boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp(522) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr<my_namespace::A>(const boost::shared_ptr<my_namespace::A> &,boost::detail::dynamic_cast_tag)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=my_namespace::B
1>          ]
1>          [location]\[source_filename].cpp(217) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::shared_ptr<T> boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<my_namespace::B,striker::A>(const boost::shared_ptr<my_namespace::A> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=my_namespace::B
1>          ]
1>C:\Libs\boost_1_44\boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp(260): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

The C++ code is more or less the following:

```
#include <list>
#include "boost/pointer_cast.hpp"
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"

struct A
{
public:
    A(const MyEnum an_enum_, const int an_int_) :
        an_enum(an_enum_),
        an_int(an_int_)
    {}

    const MyEnum an_enum;
    const int an_int;
};

struct B : public A {
public:
    B(const int some_int_, const MyStruct &a_struct_) :
        A(ENUM_OPTION_A, an_int_),
        a_struct(a_struct_)
    {}

    const MyStruct a_struct;
};


// Ussage in some function:
// ...
boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr = boost::shared_ptr<A>( new B() );
std::list<boost::shared_ptr<A>> a_list;
a_list.push_back(a_ptr);
// ...
boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr2 = a_list.front();
boost::shared_ptr<B> b_ptr = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(a_ptr2); // <-- error here
// ...
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` works ONLY with polymorphic class. And `polymorphic` class is that which has  atleast one `virtual` function, even be it the destructor.

```
//polymorphic classes
struct A
{
   virtual ~A(); //even virtual destructor makes a class polymorphic!
};
struct B : A
{
   void f();
};

//non-polymorphic classes    
struct C
{
   ~C(); //not virtual
};

struct D : C
{
   void f(); //not virtual either
};
```

In the above code, `A` and `B` are polymorphic classes, but `C` and `D` are not.

```
A *pA = new B();
B *pB = dynamic_cast<B*>(pA); //okay

C *pC = new D();
D *pD = dynamic_cast<D*>(pC);  //error -  not polymorphic class
```

Note that in `dynamic_cast`, only the source type need to be *polymorphic* in order to compile. If the destination isn't *polymorphic*, then `dynamic_cast` will return null pointer.

```
D *pD = dynamic_cast<D*>(pA);  //okay - source (pA) is polymorphic

if ( pD )  
      cout << "pD is not null" ;
else 
      cout << "pD is null";
```

Output:

```
pD is null
```

Online demo: https://web.archive.org/web/20000000000000/http://www.ideone.com/Yesxc

Comment: +1, however, why you have commented for `D::f()`; will it make polymorphic relation even if it was virtual ?

Comment: @iammilind: If `D::f()` is virtual, then `D` will be polymorphic class, though `C` will still be non-polymorphic.

Comment: true. but we will be interested for `dynamic_cast` between `C` and `D`. So it doesn't matter whether `D` is polymorphic or not.

Comment: @iammilind: If `D`is not polymorphic, then `dynamic_cast<D*>(pC)` will return NULL, if `pC` is polymorphic, or if `pC` is NOT polymorphic, then the code will not compile.

Answer (score 5):

`'dynamic_cast' : 'my_namespace::A' is not a polymorphic type` because it doesn't define or inherit a single `virtual` function. Just add a virtual destructor and you'll be fine.

`dynamic_cast` works only for such 'polymorphic' types.

Answer (score 2):

`struct A` has no virtual methods (not even a destructor), so you can't `dynamic_cast` from `A*` - only pointers to types with at least one virtual member function can be used `dynamic_cast` on. `boost::dynamic_pointer_cast` does `dynamic_cast` inside, to it's subject to same requirements.