# C++: How to treat a class as the inherited class of it?

Tags: c++

I'm making a tower defense game by using c++ & sfml.
I have the classes (object, Tower, Enemy), The classes Tower and Enemy inherite class object;

[image]

see this code:

```
int main()
{
    std::list<object*> Objects;

    .....

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        .......

        for(auto a:Objects)
        {
            for(auto b:Objects)
            {
                if(a != b && a->name == "tower" && b->name == "enemy" && distance(a, b) <= a->range)
                {
                    a->targets.push_back(b); // here's the problem, when i compile it i get:
                }                            // error: 'class object' has no member named 'targets'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is:

class 'Tower' has member 'targets' which is 'list'
and because 'Tower' inherite 'object' so i can add it's pointer to list 'objects',
I can edit 'x, y, name' but i can't edit the members in 'Tower' as the compiler told
(error: 'class object' has no member named 'targets').

What is the solution?

Comment: Can you please stop posting code as picture please!

Comment: Using [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

object a is of type object, so how does the compiler know it's a tower, even if you do?

You can cast the object to a object of type tower like this:

```
Tower* tower = dynamic_cast<Tower*>(a);
if (tower)
    tower->targets..
```

Just keep in mind - if the object you're casting wasn't actually of the type Tower, dynamic_cast will return nullptr.

To use dynamic_cast, your source type must be polymorphic - you can make the object class polymorphic easiest by adding a virtual destructor:

```
class object
{
    public:
    virtual ~object(){}
    ..
}
```

Comment: Note that regular need for dynamic casts generally indicates there is something wrong with your design

Comment: Care to elaborate @Klaus? Looks ok to me, they mention the need for a null pointer check

Comment: By running this, the only problem I encounter is that the object class is not polymorphic, but that's a compiler error, not a crash

Comment: @AlanBirtles: If there is a code example given, why it is not extended with a simple `if`? Having only a remark somewhere in the text is nice, but can be simply ignored by fast readers. So simply improve quality by adding it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to access the `targets` member of a `Tower` instance **through** a pointer to an `object`. The class `object` doesn't have a `targets` member, `Tower` has, hence the error message.

The solution is to cast `a` to a pointer to `Tower` with [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast), and after that you can use its `targets` member. To be able to use `dynamic_cast` your `object` class have to be polymorphic (for details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831863/c-why-does-a-struct-class-need-a-virtual-method-in-order-to-be-polymorphic)). You can achieve that by defining atleast 1 `virtual` function in `object`. The easiest is to define a default destructor.

```
class object {
    virtual ~object() = default;

    // ...
}
```

```
if (auto tower = dynamic_cast<Tower*>(a)) {
    tower->targets.push_back(b);
} else {
    // 'a' is not a 'Tower'.
}
```

Comment: I've just corrected my answer. `object` has to be polymorphic in order to be castable by `dynamic_cast`. If it worked for you that means you already have a `virtual` function in it, and defining a `virtual` destructor is unnecessary in that case.