# Dynamic cast - Difference between the two

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

Say I have two classes

```
class foo
{
   .......
   virtual ~foo() {..}
};

class foobar : public foo
{
};
```

The following does not cause an error:

```
foo* c = new foo();
foobar* j = dynamic_cast<foobar*>(c);
```

However the following cast causes an error at runtime:

```
foo c;
foo &d = c;
foobar& j = dynamic_cast<foobar&>(d);
```

Why does casting work with pointers but not with references?

Comment: In the first example, j will be 0 (nullptr). The second example should compile, I think, but will throw an exception.

Comment: I know my concern is why do i get a build error on the second and not on the first

Comment: You shouldn't get a build error. You should get an runtime exception.

Comment: Yep sorry a runtime exception

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831765/c-is-not-a-polymorphic-type-while-using-boostdynamic-pointer-cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast fails in both cases, as expected.

In the first case, it returns a `nullptr`, which you should test against before de-referencing the pointer. In the second case, there isn't anything that can be returned, and the cast raises an `std::bad_cast` exception. This what [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)is designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic_cast` when the pointer/reference is actually pointing to an object of a derrived class. But in your case the object is actually of class `foo`, not `foobar`. So first one will give `nullptr` and second one will raise exception.

```
 foo* ob = new foobar();
 foobar* f_ob = dynamic_cast<foobar*>(ob);
```

similar for reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `null reference`. `dynamic_cast` cannot return a nullptr to indicate that the dynamic type of this object is not compatible with target type, so it raises a std::bad_cast.